# when I run query on view I get 2 record for unique id in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two table in SqlServer Member and MemberAdress and I am generating a view vw_Member by executing following query

```
SELECT     
   m.MemberId, 
   m.MemberName, 
   m.EndCustomer,  
   m.ExpirationDate, 
   ma.DEA, 
   ma.HIN,  
   ma.Address1, 
   ma.Address2,  
   ma.City, 
   ma.State,  
   ma.OfficeContact,
   ma.OfficeContactTitle,  
   ma.OfficeContactEmail  
FROM dbo.Member m
   INNER JOIN dbo.MemberAddress ma ON (m.MemberId = ma.MemberId)
```

but the problem is that I am generating two record  for unique MemberId

Can Somebody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: can someone (asker/moderator) format the code properly

Comment: Then you have multiple addresses for those members. The inner join will join the member id with each of them. That result is not wrong but appearantly not what you need. In order to help you further you will have to provide more info on what result you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess - there are two rows in `MemberAddress` with the same `MemberId`. Maybe there's some concept modelled in there of an address type? If so, you need to decide which of those address types you should be including in this view, or if you always need *an* address, some decision on how you would prioritise the address types.

For the second, your FROM clause might look something like:

```
FROM
    dbo.Member m
        INNER JOIN  
    dbo.MemberAddress ma
        ON
            m.MemberId = ma.MemberId
        LEFT JOIN
    dbo.MemberAddress ma_anti
        ON
            m.MemberId = ma_anti.MemberId and
            ma_anti.AddressType > ma.AddressType --priority decision
WHERE
    ma_anti.MemberId is null
```

Where the join to `ma_anti` is trying to find a "better" row from `MemberAddress` than the row selected from `ma` - if the join succeeds, you don't want that row in your final result set, so that's what the `WHERE` clause is doing.

Answer (score 0):

- Are the double member ID rows valid values?

  - eg Can a Member have more then on address
  - Is there a difference in the rows contents?

---

### Making your data fit the schema

- *dbo.Member.MemberId* should be a Primary Key
- *dbo dbo.MemberAddress.MemberId* should be a foriegn key that maps to Member.MemberId.